# Date to timestring conversion one hour wrong

Tags: java, android, string, date, time

I have a Date, for example `2000-01-01T10:00:00Z` . This stands for openinghours of a shop, so this means the shop opens at 10 o'clock. The other information is useless, it is a random date.
I only need to represent this as a string so: 10:00.
For this conversion i used a simple method:

```
public String dateToString(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm");
    String time= ft.format(date);
return time;
}
```

I thought this should work, the capital HH for 24 hour representation of the hours. But when i run this code the return value is 11:00 ! 
Why is this, and how to prevent it? Does the format function take a look at my time zone and is this set wrong in the Date (i think my phone settings are mgt+1, cause i live in Holland)? And how to ignore this?

Comment: `Z` means GMT+0, so yep wrong timezone.

Comment: I had somehow the same problem in Iran. When I disable daylight saving on my OS (by using a TimeZone which does not support daylight saving) everything becomes right!

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Changing the default time zone on your host OS is not the best way to go about this. Instead (a) use the java.time classes, and (b) always specify the optional time zone arguments in the various methods on date-time classes.

Answer (score 1):

oke, found it!
Android converses a Date to the timezone of the device. I had to overrule that:

This works:

```
public String dateToString(Date date){
    SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm");
    ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String time= ft.format(date);
return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `2000-01-01T10:00:00Z` is not not at all “useless”. This describes an exact moment on the timeline, with a date, a time-of-day, and an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) which is [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself in this case.

## ISO 8601

That string format is defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

## `Instant`

You can parse this string directly as a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). That means up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2000-01-01T10:00:00Z" );
```

The `Instant` class is only the basic building-block class in Java. For more flexibility we should either:

- Assign the instant an offset-from-UTC (`ZoneOffset`) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).
- Assign the instant a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

What is the difference? A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

## `OffsetDateTime`

So if you truly wanted the time-of-day for this moment as seen in UTC, then assign an offset of UTC ([`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC)) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), and then extract a `LocalTime` object. `LocalTime` represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
LocalTime lt = odt.toLocalTime();  // 10:00:00
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to see the same moment through the lens of another time zone, to see that particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), specify a `ZoneId`. For example, that same moment in Québec would be  5 hours *behind* UTC.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );  // 2000-01-01T05:00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();  // 05:00:00
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.